# Can anyone point me to Spring MVC, Tiles, Freemarker integration example?

Tags: spring, tiles, freemarker

In my Spring MVC based applications i use Freemarker and i like it very much, but it's lacking advantages provided by Composite View pattern.

I'm thinking of trying to use Tiles2 together with Freemarker - does anyone know where do i find a simple example of SpringMVC together with Tiles2+Freemarker?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 2):

nevermind, i've solved it. i just had to specify freemarker templates in tiles definitions file

```
<definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/ftl/main.ftl">
```

and add freemarker servlet/maping to web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- FreemarkerServlet settings: -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>NoCache</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ContentType</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- FreeMarker settings: -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>template_update_delay</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value> <!-- 0 is for development only! Use higher value otherwise. -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>number_format</param-name>
        <param-value>0.##########</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

in spring configuration specify tiles as my primary view engine

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/defs/definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Was worrying about this code in the web.xml. Thanks for the answer, Walrus rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Another product you could use instead of Tiles is [SiteMesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/), which I've used in some apps. It's worth checking out.